# Javafx: Check box Listener example

Tags: javafx

i have a TreeView in which user can add roots and coordinates. coordinate's rectangle are shown horizontally in root.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static int rootNr = 0;
    private static int coordinateNr = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static final Map<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<>("Main System");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Roots");
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(tree);
        treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            TreeItem<String> treeItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (treeItem.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(child -> child.getValue().startsWith("C"))) {
                    root.setCenter(getRootsPanel(treeItem.getValue()));
            }else {
                    root.setCenter(map.get(treeItem));
            }
        });

        treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new AddMenuTreeCell());
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        root.setLeft(treeView);
        tree.getChildren().add(item1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        private TextField textField;
        public AddMenuTreeCell() {
            MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Roots");
            MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Coordinates");
            menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1, newitem2);
            newitem1.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Root" + rootNr++);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item3);
            });
            newitem2.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> newLeaf = new TreeItem<>("Coordinates" + coordinateNr++);
                TreeItem<String> uxItem1 = new TreeItem<>("X");
                map.put(uxItem1, getrightPane1());
                TreeItem<String> uyItem1 = new TreeItem<>("y");
                map.put(uyItem1, getrightPane1());
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uxItem1);
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uyItem1);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (!isEditing()) {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (!(getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)) {
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
                rect1.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect1.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect1.setFill(null);
                rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect1);
            }
        });
        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                rect2.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect2.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect2.setFill(null);
                rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect2);
            }
        });

        if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0 && root1.getCenter() == null) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect.setFill(null);
            rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect);
        }

        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y1:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X1:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root1.setLeft(vbox);
        return root1;
    }

    private static BorderPane getRootsPanel(String root) {
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("Change order");
        CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Change View");
        VBox vbox = new VBox(30, box1,box2);
        hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);
        box1.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val){
                System.out.println("Change order");
            }
        });

        box2.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val){
                System.out.println("Change View");
            }
        });

        for (Map.Entry<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getParent().getParent().getValue().equals(root)) {
                Rectangle rect1 = (Rectangle) entry.getValue().getCenter();
                if (rect1 != null) {
                    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                    rect2.setWidth(rect1.getWidth());
                    rect2.setHeight(rect1.getHeight());
                    rect2.setFill(rect1.getFill());
                    rect2.setStroke(rect1.getStroke());
                    Platform.runLater(() -> hbox.getChildren().addAll(rect2));
                }
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> root2.setLeft(hbox));
        return root2;
    }
}
```

User need check box to change rectangles order(like 1 2 3  to 3 2 1) & view (horizontal to vertical).

if there were only 2 coordinates, i can solve this using Gridpane but here all added rectangles should change order by selecting first check box and by selecting 2nd view should be changed and when both are selected then order and view both should be changed.

Please any hint would be fine.

Thank you