# Javafx: Checkbox Listener on newly added item in treeView

Tags: javafx

I asked this question but didn't get any response. [Javafx: Check box Listener example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886512/javafx-check-box-listener-example)   Please i need help with this problem of mine. code is

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static int rootNr = 0;
    private static int coordinateNr = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static final Map<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<>("Main System");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Roots");
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(tree);
        treeView.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
            TreeItem<String> treeItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (treeItem.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(child -> child.getValue().startsWith("C"))) {
                    root.setCenter(getRootsPanel(treeItem.getValue()));
            }else {
                    root.setCenter(map.get(treeItem));
            }
        });

        treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new AddMenuTreeCell());
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        root.setLeft(treeView);
        tree.getChildren().add(item1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class AddMenuTreeCell extends TextFieldTreeCell<String> {
        private ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        private TextField textField;
        public AddMenuTreeCell() {
            MenuItem newitem1 = new MenuItem("Insert Roots");
            MenuItem newitem2 = new MenuItem("Insert Coordinates");
            menu.getItems().addAll(newitem1, newitem2);
            newitem1.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Root" + rootNr++);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(item3);
            });
            newitem2.setOnAction(arg0 -> {
                TreeItem<String> newLeaf = new TreeItem<>("Coordinates" + coordinateNr++);
                TreeItem<String> uxItem1 = new TreeItem<>("X");
                map.put(uxItem1, getrightPane1());
                TreeItem<String> uyItem1 = new TreeItem<>("y");
                map.put(uyItem1, getrightPane1());
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uxItem1);
                newLeaf.getChildren().add(uyItem1);
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLeaf);
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (!isEditing()) {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    if (!(getTreeItem().isLeaf() && getTreeItem().getParent() == null)) {
                        setContextMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static BorderPane getrightPane1() {
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        BorderPane root1 = new BorderPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
               Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
                rect1.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect1.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect1.setFill(null);
                rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                root1.setCenter(rect1);
            }
        });
        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                rect2.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                rect2.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                rect2.setFill(null);
                rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
                root1.setCenter(rect2);
            }
        });

        if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0 && root1.getCenter() == null) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rect.setFill(null);
            rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
            root1.setCenter(rect);
        }

        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y1:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X1:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root1.setLeft(vbox);
        return root1;
    }

    private static BorderPane getRootsPanel(String root) {
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("Change order");
        CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Change View");
        box1.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
             //   rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
             //   rect2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
               // rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
               // rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
            }
        });
        box2.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {

            } else {

            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(30, box1,box2);

        for (Map.Entry<TreeItem<String>, BorderPane> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getParent().getParent().getValue().equals(root)) {
                Rectangle rect1 = (Rectangle) entry.getValue().getCenter();
                if (rect1 != null) {
                    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();
                    rect2.setWidth(rect1.getWidth());
                    rect2.setHeight(rect1.getHeight());
                    rect2.setFill(rect1.getFill());
                    rect2.setStroke(rect1.getStroke());
                    Platform.runLater(() -> hbox.getChildren().addAll(rect2));
                }
            }
        }
        hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Platform.runLater(() -> root2.setLeft(hbox));
        return root2;
    }
}
```

TreeView in which user can add roots and coordinates. coordinate's rectangle are shown horizontally in root.

User need first check box to change **rectangles order**(like 1 2 3 to 3 2 1) & second to change **view** (horizontal to vertical). If there were only 2 Leafs this can be done with code given in Comments (i didn't put 2nd box code in comment because one i have can only use 2 leafs).

These check-boxes should have effect on all generated rectangles not just 2.

This would be a big help. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx: Check box Listener example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886512/javafx-check-box-listener-example)

Comment: @trashgod, because of no response i asked again.

Comment: never duplicate a question - if you dont get an answer, try to edit/clarify the original or add a bounty (once you get some reputation to spare :)

Comment: @kleopatra, thanks i am new to Stackoverflow so i didn't know. i will keep that in mind next time. thanks. So any guidance on my question?please